# Django 1.11 - Inline Admin Model - Error: admin.E106

Tags: python, django

I want to access the Image model in the Art admin page as it's written [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) but something goes wrong:

*/gallery/models.py:*

```
class Image:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    thumb = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Art, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
```

*/product/admin.py:*

```
class ArtImage(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 3

class ArtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ArtImage]

admin.site.register(Art, ArtAdmin)
```

When I apply the makemigrations command I get

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>   ERRORS:
>   : (admin.E106) The value of 'product.admin.ArtImage.model' must be a Model.

What could it be?

Comment: The error suggests that `Image` is not the model you have shown. Perhaps you have defined another `Image` class in your `admin.py`, or you have imported the wrong class.

Comment: Thank you, Alasdair, you're correct. I wasn't extending the models.Model with my Image model. That's what I get for working late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was pointed out by Alasdair in the comment, I forgot to extend the models.Model when writing the Image class, that's why it wasn't being recognised as a Model instance.

The Image class should look like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    thumb = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Art, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
```

Piece of advice: don't code when tired, you make silly mistakes

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just accidentally left a trailing comma when defining the inline:

```py
class PhotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Photo, # <-- watch out for the comma
    extra = 0
```